# How to upload 1 hour old files to S3 using fluentd?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fluentd, fluentdata

I have successfully upload files to S3 using fluentd. I am trying to upload  one hour old files to S3 using fluentd.

Eg. fluentd only upload files which are 1 hour old and it should not upload files which are not 1 hour old. I only want to upload files which are currently one hour old. 
How to achieve this, I am new to fluentd ?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to upload past data is to use [Embulk](http://www.embulk.org/docs/) :)
These original author for both is [@frsyuki](https://github.com/frsyuki), and originally designed as Fluentd for stream (current) data, and Embulk for batch (past) data.

Comment: Cant we do this task with Fluentd ?

Comment: It's not impossible, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Can you tell me the way to do this ?